# NAV fill with last week range in a date field

Tags: navision

I'm trying to figure how to get the last week range to pass to a date field.
I'm using the page 408 G/L Balance by dimension and my goal is to fill in the page open the column "DateFilter" with the last week until today (05/06/2018..today)

I tried to use the CALCDATE function and the option "CW" for the expression but I can't find the solution.. ('<-CM - %1W>')

Answer (score 0):

You need

`rec.SETFITER(“Date Filter”, “<-CW>..%1”, today);`

Comment: My problem is I can get the range but can't assign to my field "Datefield" of my page

Comment: You don't need to. Setfilter will do what you want. Date Filter is of type FlowFilter. It can't be assigned directly.